# How to delete an exact element in a bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash, unset

I am trying to remove **just the first appearance** of any one keyword from a bash array.

```
ARRAY=(foo bar and any number of keywords)
keywords=(red, rednet, rd3.0)
```

I remove the keyword like this: `ARRAY=( ${ARRAY[@]/"$keyword"/} )` then if "red' is the first found keyword, it will strip '**red**' from both keywords and return "foo bar net" instead of "foo bar rednet".

Edit: Here is example, hopefully this makes it clearer.

```
for keyword in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
      if [ "$keyword" = "red" ] || [ "$keyword" = "rd3.0" ] || [ "$keyword" = "rednet" ]; then
           # HERE IS TROUBLE
           ARRAY=( ${ARRAY[@]/"$keyword"/} )
           echo "ARRAY is now ${ARRAY[@]}"
           break
      fi
 done
```

Which if the `ARRAY=(red rednet rd3.0)` returns **net rd3.0**  instead of **rednet rd3.0**

If I use unset,: `unset ${ARRAY["$keyword"]}` bash complains if the rd3.0 is in the array: `:syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")`
What is the safe way to unset or remove just an exact match from an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `unset` command with the array value at `index`, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ARRAY=(foo bar any red alpha number of keywords rd3.0 and)
keywords=(red, rednet, rd3.0)

index=0
for keyword in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
      if [ "$keyword" = "red" ] || [ "$keyword" = "rd3.0" ] || [ "$keyword" = "rednet" ]; then
           # HERE IS TROUBLE
           # ARRAY=( ${ARRAY[@]/"$p"/} )
           unset ARRAY[$index]
           echo "ARRAY is now: ${ARRAY[@]}"
           break
      fi
      let index++
 done
```

Comment: I see. I can do that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't actually remove the element from the array, just sets it to a blank. So, if you run `a=( a b c ); unset a[1]; echo ${a[1]}` you will not get `c` as you might expect, but whatever is in a blank element. To truly remove the element, you should follow the `unset` with something like `a=( ${a[@] }` to shift the other elements forward to take the blank ones place.

Comment: To reset indexes after the loop: `ARRAY=("${ARRAY[@]}")`

Answer (score 0):

First: You should use quotation marks around your keys in the arrays. This avoids problems with for example rd3.0.

Like that:

```
ARRAY=("foo" "bar" "and" "any" "number" "of" "keywords")
keywords=("red", "rednet", "rd3.0")
```

In my opinion you need to copy the array and then use a for loop to filter the keywords. Exit the for loop after the first successful filtering. After that copy it back without the empty array elements. See [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/) short examples (paragraph 10).

More on arrays: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html (everything you will ever need)

Comment: In my script, this actually is a copy of the initial array. I just shortened it here. I am using for loops as well to iterate over it, and do exit. I have followed your link and seen it many times...my question is not so much about arrays as it is handling text I think. I am getting a string like this originally "red rednet rd3.0". Should I reformat to intersperse colons you think?

Comment: By colons, do you by chance really mean quotation marks? Colon is `:`, quotation marks are `""`.

Comment: Michael Kjörling: To long ago, but I see no colons in my post. You seem to be right. :-)